# Oracle VBox wrong resolutions

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualbox, linux-distributions, google-chrome-os

the fact that am posting here means i have already wasted enough time researching on this, so my vbox goes to the right resolution for windows 7 but i had kali linux and chrome os all go to a 4:3 (800x600 or 1024x768, ...) screen ratio, my screen resolution is 1366x768 (16:9). I have tried the vboxmanager setextradata command, i have extensionpack downloaded just nothing works. Any help please would be appreciated. Am on windows 8.1(host os)

**EDIT** Only chrome Os and Kali linux, sorry about that

Comment: Have you installed the VboxAdditions on the virtual machines? you need to install this in order to get the window adjust properly to the screen resolution.

Comment: If its the one from devices menu you are talking about then i tried that too, error mounting that

Comment: yes that one, did you check if the device is already mounted? the problem is that you need to install those to get the resolution changes.

Comment: All i did was after launching the vm, go to devices menu and select install(in this case it was the last option in the menu) so whatever you are saying can you guide me through briefly because i got none of that @genaro

Comment: sure, you can see all the information on how to install this on the following:

Comment: sure, first you can check if you have enabled the vbox addition feature to achieve this. Start your virtual machine and go to the File->Preferences->Screen on the menu bar there is the size to some scale or automatic scale. If you can't change that you need to install the vbox additions, you can see all the information on how to install this on the following:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm

Comment: Apparently i can change that

Comment: ok, if you can set this to automatic now go to the View menu and select the option "Auto-resize guest Display" now you must be able to maximize the window and see it with the correct scale

Comment: That option is disabled, the view->auto resize guest display

Comment: then you still need to install the vbox additions, once you installed it restarts the vbox manager and the machine to ensure the changes.

Comment: Tried looking but turns out there is no additions for chrome os, decided to use it as it is because it has already taken too much of my time, some guy referred to it as crippleware which is hilarious, thanks though a bunch